# Flask application on uwsgi gives a TypeError: 'Flask' object is not iterable

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I'm running Python/Flask application on Python 3.5 in a virtualenv on Arch Linux. The application is run by a uwsgi server that is connected via socket to Nginx.

When I perform a request, I get the following uwsgi error:

```
Mar 23 02:38:19 saltminion1.local uwsgi[20720]: TypeError: 'Flask' object is not iterable
```

This is the callable that uwsgi is configured to use:

```py
def create_app(config=None, import_name=None):
    if import_name is None:
        import_name = DefaultConfig.PROJECT

    app = Flask(import_name, instance_path=INSTANCE_FOLDER_PATH, instance_relative_config=True)

    configure_app(app, config)
    configure_database(app)
    configure_logging(app)
    configure_error_handlers(app)
    configure_blueprints(app)

    return app
```

Things work fine when I start the application using the built-in HTTP server both on the local OS X development workstation and on Arch/Ubuntu vagrant boxes.

Problem is: After adding debug statements it became clear the error occurs at some point in the Flask code itself and not within my app. How can I get a stack trace here to troubleshoot better?

Comment: Can you show the file that defines the callable you're passing to `uwsgi`?

Comment: Updated with the relevant method, I can add more of the methods if necessary.

Comment: Your question inspired me to add some more debug code and I quickly found out the issue. Thanks for this question! It led me to rethink the whole set-up. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A WSGI app (which Flask is), is a callable object.  That's what uWSGI expects to be passed to `callable`.  You're passing an app factory, which is also callable, but you need to pass it the *result* of that call, because the app factory isn't a WSGI application itself.

The factory function can be called directly in the configuration.  The `module` and `callable` options can also be combined in just `module`.

```
module = my_app:create_app()
```

This tells uWSGI to import `my_app`, find `my_app.create_app`, and call it.  The result of that, the Flask app, is what's actually used as the callable.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer: I configured uwsgi with `callable = create_app` which was a function that returns a Flask "application". But uwsgi actually wants the application object.